# Ignore TextInput pointer events

Tags: react-native

I have a view with a `TextInput` that you can edit. At a certain the `TextInput` should not be editable, and it's container should respond to a click on it in a different manner.

Setting `editable: false` in the `TextInput` does disable editing, but the pointer events to the touchable container above are not recieved. Even setting `pointerEvents: "none"` on it will not work.
If I replace the `TextInput` with any other component, clicks are recieved.

My only solution right now is to replace my `TextInput` with `Text` when I want the read-only-clickable state, but the styling gets messed up when I do that and I need to adjust the `Text` to position itself like the `TextInput` which isn't as trivial as I imagined it would be.

I should point out - I am only testing this on Android at the moment.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: One hack could be to place a transparent touchablehighlight on the textinput when the state changes to not editable.

Comment: That's actually the current situation, it still steals the touch event.

Comment: I have the same issue. My particular case is that I want to open a modal with datepicker when I press on input, but I want disallow any direct editing of the value and make input read only. On Android if I move TextInput inside TouchableOpacity, the latter won't receive touch events. It works fine on iOS though.

Comment: Are you sure you need a `TextInput` in that case? If you never directly edit it, you can just use `Text`